# Smart charging circuit for NiMH battery pack

Tags: arduino, batteries, battery-charging, solar-cell, charger

I want to build a solar powered charger for a niMh battery pack to run a microcontroller. What are the fundamentals of building a smart circuit that will not overcharge the battery and will also allow current to be pulled directly from the panel

Comment: Applicable to what your doing :
http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/alex9000/the-solar-pocket-factory-an-invention-adventure They have arduino shield that regulates Nimh battery charge for 35 dollars. Product is listed on the right of the page. This does not directly answer your question on how to build solar powered Nimh battery pack

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In most cases with a small panel and a NimH battery the peak charge rate is below 1C and the supply varies with insolation (sunshine level). In addition, if the battery is near the panel the battery temperature varies with insolation. All these factors make most usual NimH charge termination algorithms and methods inapplicable.

- Negative delta V detection is problematic at best when you charge V is variable.
- Delta temperature rate rise is utterly swamped if the cell is sun exposed and
- Absolute cell temperature is not a good measure of endpoint for the same reason.

In such cases a very reasonable charging strategy is to terminate charge at 1.45V per cell.

This can be adjusted for temperature. In my designs I also add charge current sensing and adjust the threshold down if the cell is still accepting large charge currents when almost charged. This helps compensate for a degree of variability between cells. Cells of different models and different manufacturers are usually reasonably consistent with the 1.45 / cell setting but some are fully charged at as little as 1.35V/cell.

If the cell output is wanted for other purposes when not needed for charging then charge control can use a series regulator or on/off series switch. If the battery is the only load then a shunt regulator to dissipate excess power can be
a good choice for smaller panels. Note that if the panel is taken "off charge" its voltage will drop and hysteresis will be needed to prevent endless on off charge cycling.